# how to get json object from js array

Tags: javascript, json

```
let awards = ["earth","sun","moon"];
let a = JSON.stringify(awards);
console.log(a);
Result: -["earth","sun","moon"] // no difference?
```

In my database, text field, I have this:

```
{"earth","sun","moon"};
```

**update**

from this I get php array using:

```
$arr = json_decode($data['planets'], true);
```

What is the difference between `["earth","sun","moon"]` and `{"earth","sun","moon"}`

And how to get `{"earth","sun","moon"}` from js array - `["earth","sun","moon"];`?

Comment: Object should always be a key value pair.

Comment: @JonathanHamel, `php, mysql` on server side

Comment: `{"earth","sun","moon"}` this is invalid json. `{}` - encodes object expecting `"key": value` pairs. But you have something array-like (comma separated  values)

Comment: It appears to be the Javascript Set notation.

Comment: `let awards = ["earth","sun","moon"]; const str =\`{${awards.map(x => JSON.stringify(x))}}\`` should give the value you want.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, see my update pls. Seems it is no invalid json. It produces a regular php array

Comment: @qadenza It is invalid json. You could simply try to decode it `JSON.parse('{"earth","sun","moon"}') // throws` you need to replace curly braces with square ones to make it valid json string. `JSON.parse('["earth","sun","moon"]') //works`

Comment: This might be a side effect of json_decode when you pass true in the second parameter. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object will have the format { key : value }. For example, { "Earth" : "Planet" } is an object. But {"Earth", "Planet" } is not an object.

["earth","sun","moon"] is an array of strings. There is no way to just convert an array of strings into an object, because the operation doesn't really make sense.

Are you sure you are not missing colons in your database text field?

Comment: you can convert an array of strings into an object : Object.assign({}, ['a','b','c']);   ES6:{ ...['a', 'b', 'c'] }

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Object.assign({}, ['a','b','c']) will result in {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"} 

The keys in this case will be the integers 0,1,2... and the values will be the elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `["earth","sun","moon"]` and `{"earth","sun","moon"}` is that the former is an array and the latter is a set.

```
var words = ["earth","sun","moon"];
var set = new Set(words) // {"earth","sun","moon"}
```

As for the `json_decode`, you need to specify if you want an associative array instead of an object. This could be causing the Array to change to a Set changes to the array in `json.decode($data['planets'], true)`